# How can I set cookie from server side to the target domain with ajax post request

Tags: ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I have two domains `a.com` and `b.com`.

I want to send an ajax post request from `a.com` to `b.com`, and then, `b.com` should set a cookie from the server side to `b.com`.

But the cookie can not be set via ajax request.

Is there any way to set a cross-domain cookie from server side via an ajax post request?